# Macchanger not working automatically

Tags: ubuntu, networking, mac-address

So I installed `macchanger` and it works manually, but I also set it up in the installation to automatically change the MAC address when a network change is detected in a device and it does not work at all.

I tried the official guide but it did not help. I use the latest Ubuntu 18 LTS version. I reconnect with WI-FI but it does not give me a new MAC address. I also tend to get same network IP even though I changed MAC on my home network (to which I have very limited access as it is dorm network). It might be because I am using a switch.

Comment: Refer to this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/267338/wlan-and-macchanger If it helps you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing with >sudo apt-get install macchanger
That should solve all previous delays in new IP geberation

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add some explanation why you think this approach solves the problem stated. Also, I am not sure if the_IP-address_ is really the OP's concern here. It sounded like a secondary problem and even so, it was getting _the same_ IP on the home network most times, not a delay in the address assignment.